# Wait until activity was closed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I use Xamarin Auth to authenticate with OneDrive in my android app. I assume this would work, but I have the issue that when the activity for the login prompt is opened the programm will just continue and not wait for the auth to finish.
How can I wait until it's closed or wrap this in a other way async?

Code:

```
        private IDictionary<string, string> authenticationResponseValues;

    protected override async Task<AccountSession> GetAuthenticationResultAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => ShowWebView());

        return new AccountSession(authenticationResponseValues, this.ServiceInfo.AppId, AccountType.MicrosoftAccount)
        {
            CanSignOut = true
        };
    }

    private void ShowWebView()
    {
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: MSA_CLIENT_ID,
                scope: string.Join(",", scopes),
                authorizeUrl: new Uri(GetAuthorizeUrl()),
                redirectUrl: new Uri(RETURN_URL));


        auth.Completed += SetAccountInfos;

        var intent = auth.GetUI(Application.Context);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
    }

    private void SetAccountInfos(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs);
            Debug.WriteLine(eventArgs.Account == null ? "IS NULL" : "IS NOT NULL");

            if (eventArgs.Account != null)
            {
                OAuthErrorHandler.ThrowIfError(eventArgs.Account.Properties);
                authenticationResponseValues = eventArgs.Account.Properties;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you presenting your login? Via a `startActivityForResult`, a sequential series of Activities...

Comment: I added the code of the intent. Sorry, I forget it in the first place. I tried it with startActivityForResult with different int values aswell (e.g. -1,0, 1), but that that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think using async tactic is reasonable, because app runs before login result returns.

Try to use sync way. Make a login page. If success, then switch to your real app.

Comment: There is a login page. But the problem is after Application.Context.StartActivity(intent); it just leaves the method and returns the new AccountSession with null for authenticationResponseValues since SetAccountInfos wasn't called. I need a way to wait until the this method was called to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Here my code:

```
await ShowWebView();
return new AccountSession(authenticationResponseValues, ServiceInfo.AppId,
            AccountType.MicrosoftAccount)
{
    CanSignOut = true
};

private Task<bool> ShowWebView()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(OneDriveAuthenticationConstants.MSA_CLIENT_ID, string.Join(",", OneDriveAuthenticationConstants.Scopes), new Uri(GetAuthorizeUrl()),
            new Uri(OneDriveAuthenticationConstants.RETURN_URL));

        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
        {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                OAuthErrorHandler.ThrowIfError(eventArgs.Account.Properties);
                authenticationResponseValues = eventArgs.Account.Properties;
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            }
        };

        var intent = auth.GetUI(Application.Context);
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

And the link to the class in the repo: https://github.com/Apply-Solutions/MoneyManager/blob/master/Src/MoneyManager.Droid/Src/AndroidAuthenticationProvider.cs